# Extracting embedded control from PDF document using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#-4.0, itext

I have searched for this functionality but unable to find anything related. I have seen various examples to extract image, text and Acro Fields from PDF document but I want something different. I have converted an excel sheet to PDF which has couple of ActiveX TextFields on it. After converted to PDF the fields are not interactive. I am reading the PDF file from a C# application and I want to retrieve the coordinates of those ActiveX Text fields and then need to remove those fields. I am trying to read the PDF file resources through,

```
var fields = (PdfDictionary)page.Get(PdfName.CONTENTS);
```

I am not sure what correct enum value to use or whether the fields can be retrieved from this way or not. 
Sample PDF file can be viewed from here [PDF File Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wcffnbdym5d9vu7/Excel_Form.pdf)

Update: So far I have managed to identify that the ActiveX text field when exported from excel to pdf is like this (Sorry if I get this wrong),

```
<</Type/XObject/Subtype/Form/BBox[ 0 0 377.07 40.005] /Matrix[ 0.19094 0 0 1.7998 0 0] /Filter/FlateDecode/Length 155>>
```

I have also retrieved these values in my code. I just need the coordinates of each field and my guess is that BBox and Matrix values has something to do with this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Essentially, if the fields are not (Acroform or XFA) form fields, they are no fields, there merely are lines which we (viewing the PDF) consider a field box. Thus, in general, you'd have to collect the lines and and look for specific rectangles. In case of your specific PDF, though, individual "fields" are represented using individual xobjects. So you could get the coordinates using the data you updated your post with plus the current transformation matrix at the time the xobject is painted, e.g. `3.92 0 0 0.40333 183.42 582.54 cm /Meta9 Do` for the company name. This is quite brittle, though.

Comment: Thanks mkl for your response. I don't understand it completely "you could get the coordinates using the data you updated your post with plus the current transformation matrix at the time the xobject is painted". I have placed these XOBjects from MS Excel and  then converted it to PDF. The application doesn't know the coordinates that are used to place the XObjects. From value "3.92 0 0 0.40333 183.42 582.54" I can understand that 183.42 and 582.54 mention the position but where can I obtain the dimensions?

Comment: *From value ... I can understand that ...* - furthermore `3.92 0 0 0.40333` is a scaling sub-matrix which is applied after the `0.19094 0 0 1.7998` matrix you already found. Applying this scaling to the bounding box size `377.07 40.005` should result in the dimension of the xobject. Unless the xobject itself has some margin,  they should be the "field" dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for finding a solution I now think that getting the dimension of the field (Non Acro Field) is not possible and atleast I am not seeing a way to do this. What I have done instead is came up with a work around.

The scenario was that I was creating form from MS Excel and and wanted to convert them to interactive pdf files. The reason for creating them in C# was to make this as a batch process. I places various text fields on the worksheet in Excel and then passed the PDF file to the C# application so that all the fields are converted to interactive text fields and end user is able to fill them and then submit them to server which is another story.

The work around that I did was to place images instead of text fields. I placed a single color image on the worksheet and resized/placed them like I placed the text fields. I placed the JPG image because then in C# application I was able to read the PDF document, read all the JPG images from the file, retrieved their width, height, xaxis, yaxis and then I have drawn textfields using iTextSharp on those coordinates. I know my requirement was unique and incase anyone have same requirements then following is the code which I have used,

```
public static void ProcessRequest(PdfReader reader)
    {
        PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
        MyImageRenderListener listener = new MyImageRenderListener();

        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            parser.ProcessContent(i, listener);
        }

        if (listener != null)
        {
            bool success = DrawTextFields(reader, pdfPath, newFullFilePath, listener.ImageCoordinates);
        }
    }
```

And below is the custom listener class.

```
public class MyImageRenderListener : IRenderListener
{
    public void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) { }
    public void BeginTextBlock() { }
    public void EndTextBlock() { }
    public List<ImageCoordinates> ImageCoordinates = new List<ImageCoordinates>();


    public void RenderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        PdfImageObject image = renderInfo.GetImage();
        PdfName filter = image.Get(PdfName.FILTER) as PdfName;

        // PdfName.DCTDECODE   --  (For JPG Images)
        // PdfName.JPXDECODE   --  (For JP2 Images)
        // PdfName.FLATDECODE  --  (For PNG Images)
        // PdfName.LZWDECODE   --  (For TIFF Images)

        if (filter != null)
        {
            if (filter == PdfName.DCTDECODE)
            {
                        Matrix ctm = renderInfo.GetImageCTM();
                        ImageCoordinates coord = new ImageCoordinates();
                        coord.Width = ctm[Matrix.I11];
                        coord.Height = ctm[Matrix.I22];
                        coord.XAxis = ctm[Matrix.I31];
                        coord.YAxis = ctm[Matrix.I32];

                        ImageCoordinates.Add(coord);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The ImageCoordinates class is a simple class containing properties.

```
class ImageCoordinates
{
    private float width;
    public float Width
    {
        get { return width; }
        set { width = value; }
    }

    private float height;
    public float Height
    {
        get { return height; }
        set { height = value; }
    }

    private float xaxis;
    public float XAxis
    {
        get { return xaxis; }
        set { xaxis = value; }
    }

    private float yaxis;
    public float YAxis
    {
        get { return yaxis; }
        set { yaxis = value; }
    }
}
```

I haven't mentioned DrawTextField method here because a lot of tutorials are present online for drawing TextFields on PDF documents.